# Javascript - How to set the property working?

Tags: javascript

here is my code which is not working

```js
function gauche() {
    var voiture = document.getElementsByClassName("voiture")[0];
    var position = window.getComputedStyle(voiture).left;
    alert(position);
    position = parseInt(position, 10) - 30 + "px";
    alert(position);
}
```

I want to move "voiture" position 30px to the left. So I want to subtract 30 from the position.
This alert well 30px, then this alert well 0px (because 30 - 30 = 0)
But unfortunately, it doesn't update on my page. My "voiture" div is always with 30 px and not width 0px. Thanks

Comment: You are just missing: `voiture.style.left = position` at the end.

Comment: The statement starting with `var position` does nothing but copy the string from the `left` property to `position`. It updates only on the _copy_. However, we’d need to see all of your relevant HTML and CSS to solve this as you cannot simply “write” to a `getComputedStyle` property.

Answer (score 2):

Use `voiture.offsetLeft;` instead of `window.getComputedStyle(voiture).left;` so you don't have to parse it.

> The HTMLElement.offsetLeft read-only method returns the number of
>   pixels that the upper left corner of the current element is offset to
>   the left within the HTMLElement.offsetParent node.

and to set the position simply: `voiture.style.left = voiture.offsetLeft - 30 + 'px';`

[offsetLeft doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft)

[element.style.left doc](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_left.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DOM element's `style` property:

```
voiture.style.left = parseInt(position, 10) - 30 + "px";
```

Also, there's a very very wrong assumption in your code: you think that setting *current `left` value* to a local variable bounds its value to the element, while this won't happen. Whenever you want to change a DOM element (and this applies to any of its properties), you need to set its properties again instead of assuming that changing a local variable will change the element.